# USB 802.11ac adapter with in-tree Linux driver

Tags: usb, linux, wireless, raspberry-pi, network-adapter

I am looking for a Wi-Fi adapter with:

- 802.11ac, 2.4 and 5GHz bands
- USB interface, possibly USB 2.0 to avoid the interference associated with USB 3.0
- Preferably a small dongle with a standard SMA connector to attach a larger antenna
- *critical* in-tree Linux driver
- For bonus points, find one with 802.11r support

The background is I want a robust antenna for a robot I am building from a Raspberry Pi / Odroid C2 type device, but I do not want to mess around with modules and tainting the kernel.

I want a plug and play experience with the drivers built into the kernel. I will run the latest Ubuntu for ARMv8 and will happily use mainline kernels if a newer one is needed. As long as if I re-image the device, I do not need to compile and insert modules.

So far I have looked through the Linux source code and tried to cross-reference with the internet to identify a possible device. I could not find any.

Cheers!